# On mouse hover stop jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this great script for vertical slideshow.
My problem is that I can't find a way to stop the slideshow on mouse over.
Please could you help me ? Thank you in advance !

```
setInterval(

    function() {
        $('#ticker div').each(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                'top': '-=10px',
            }, 120, 

            function() {
                var top = parseInt($(this).css('top').replace('px', '')) +
                        parseInt($(this).css('height').replace('px', ''));

                if (top < 0) {
                    //console.log('removing', this)
                    var clone = $(this).clone();
                    var parent = $(this).parent();
                    clone.css('top', '550px');
                    $(this).remove();
                    parent.append(clone);
                }  
            })
        })
    }, 40
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample fiddle in order to help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you store the intervalID, you can stop the interval. This could be useful to you. The code looks something like below:

```
var intervalID = null;
function startSlideshow() {
    intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        //do stuff
    }, 40);
}

$("#mySlideshow")
    .mouseover(function() {
        if(intervalID) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        startSlideshow(); // restart slideshow when the user isn't hovering anymore
    });

startSlideshow(); //initially start slideshow.
```

You can find more information about clearInterval at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code -

```
$("#ticker div").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop();
});
```